# Generate numbers in Ruby that aren't equal to other numbers?

Tags: ruby, random, numbers

Basically I am generating numbers and they can't be equal to any other numbers I've generated. Is there a quicker way to do this because it looks slightly ridiculous.

Thanks

```
#possible generated values
x1 = 0
x2 = 1
x3 = 2

#generate co-ordinates
x4 = rand(7)
until x4 != x1 && x4 != x1+1 && x4 != x1+2 && x4 != x2 && x4 != x2+1 && x4 != x2+2 && x4 != x3 && x4 != x3+1 && x4 != x3+2 do
  x4 = rand(7)
end

#possible generated values
y1 = 0
y2 = 1
y3 = 2

y4 = rand(7)
until y4 != y1 && y4 != y1+1 && y4 != y1+2 && y4 != y2 && y4 != y2+1 && y4 != y2+2 && y4 != y3 && y4 != y3+1 && y4 != y3+2 do
  y4 = rand(7)
end
```

Comment: Seeing code like this is a sign you need to read more about the methods available on Array, Set and Enumerable. They have some very handy tools in there that help solve problems like this, so spending a little time here and there to learn a new trick is always worth the effort.

Comment: Once your code is working and you want to improve it by refactoring/rewriting, the question becomes off-topic for Stack Overflow and on-topic for [codereview.se].

Answer (score 6):

For Ruby 1.9+

```
(0..6).to_a.sample(x)
```

or for older versions

```
(0..6).to_a.shuffle.take(x)
```

where `x` is the number of integers you want to take. Since `rand(7)` does not include the number 7, you need your range to be one less than the number you'd pass to `rand`.

And obviously you can't take more numbers than are in the range.

Comment: Or just `(0..6).to_a.sample(x)` (for ruby 2.0+, I think) -- docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-sample

Comment: Good call, `sample` has been around since 1.9+ but I often overlook it.